# A word meaning "pertaining to the routine duties of life"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to recall a word that describes all the things a person does to stay alive and function in society, e.g. cooking dinner, paying bills, or driving to work. These things are routine and mundane, but nevertheless must be done to keep one's life going. It's a word like obligatory, but more confined to life.

An example sentence could be (assuming this word is an adjective), "On Saturday I went to the park, but I also took care of some [blank] tasks like mowing the lawn.". If this word is a noun, an example could be, "I enjoy the electives in my life, but the [blank] just grinds me down.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is ***quotidian***. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quotidian) says:

> Quotidian activities or experiences are basic, everyday activities or
>   experiences

.

Comment: Yes, and pedestrian or prosaic, too.

Comment: Yep, this is the one I was looking for.